# Spring JPA : REQUIRES_NEW propagation not working

Tags: spring, jpa, transactions

I have the following scenario where I have one controller containing two functions (`saveAudit` and `saveProduct`). Each one persists an object,**I would like to separate transactions between those functions**.

throwed exception on `saveProduct` function should not rollback transaction on `saveAudit` function :

***My repositories/ DAO :***

```
public interface AuditRepository extends JpaRepository<Audit, String> {
}

public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, String> {
}
```

***My controller:***

```
@RestController
@Transactional
public class ProductController {

    private final ProductreRepository productRepository;
    private final Auditrepository auditRepository;


    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    void saveAudit()
    {
        auditRepository.saveAudit(Audit.builder().action("action1").build());
    }

    @PostMapping(ApiPaths.PRODUCTS)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ProductDTO addNewProduct() {
        ProductDTO res =  productRepository.saveProduct(Product.builder().label("product1").build());
        saveAudit();
        int h=1/0; // => throw exception to rollback product creation
        return res;
    }
}
```

***Logs:***

```
Participating in existing transaction
```

Answer (score 0):

its same class proxy will not work.
move below method to @Service class and inject in your controller or annotate   @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) in  auditRepository.saveAudit

```
 @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void saveAudit()
    {
        auditRepository.saveAudit(Audit.builder().action("action1").build());
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).